# Ionic, interrupt/stop IonContent scrollToBottom or scrollToTop action

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have long text page in ionic. I have 2 buttons which triggers **scrollToBottom** and **scrollToTop** actions.

Since page is pretty long I put scroll duration 30 seconds.
I have 2 problems here:

1. How to stop scrolling action once I called it ? I tried to call **scrollToPoint** after calling **scrollToBottom** or try to scroll manually by mouse but nothing can stop the triggered action.
2. Why does this scrolling go at regular speed and end up extremely slow. Is there a way to make the scroll work at the same speed all the time?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't, the animation must end.
2. No, there is not property to control the animation speed. But if you would like, you can use [ionic animations](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/animations) to create your own custom scroll animation. But that would be reinventing the wheel. Up to you.